# In what sense is IO monad special (if at all)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, io-monad

After diving into monads I understand that they are a general concept to allow chaining computations inside some context (failing, non-determinism, state, etc) and there is no magic behind them.

Still IO monad feels even if not magic, but special.

- you cannot escape IO monad like you can with other monads
- IO action can only be run by the `main` function
- IO is always at the bottom of a monad transformers chain
- implementation of IO monad is unclear and source code shows some Haskell internals

What are the reasons for the points above? What makes IO so special?

**Update**: in pure code evaluation order doesn't matter. But it does matter when doing IO (we want to save customer before we read it). From what I understand IO monad gives us such ordering guarantees. Is it a property of a monad in general or it is something specific to IO monad?

Answer (score 8):

> you cannot escape IO monad like you can with other monads

I'm not sure what you mean by “escape”. If you mean, somehow unwrap the internal representation of the monadic values (e.g. list -> sequence of cons-cells) – that is an implementation detail. In fact, you can define [an `IO` *emulation* in pure Haskell](http://chrisdone.com/posts/pure-io-tryhaskell) – basically just a `State` over a lot of globally-available data. That would have all the semantics of `IO`, but without actually interacting with the real world, only a simulation thereof.

If you mean, you can “extract values” from within the monad – nope, that's not in general possible, even for most pure-haskell monads. For instance, you can't extract a value from `Maybe a` (could be `Nothing`) or `Reader b a` (what if `b` is uninhabited?)

> `IO` action can only be run by the `main` function

Well, in a sense, *everything* can only be run by the `main` function. Code that's not in some way invoked from `main` will only sit there, you could replace it with `undefined` without changing anything.

> IO is always at the bottom of a monad transformers chain

True, but that's also the case for e.g. `ST`.

> Implementation of `IO` monad is unclear and source code shows some Haskell internals

Again: implementation is just, well, an implementation detail. The complexity of `IO` implementations actually has a lot to do with it being highly optimised; the same is also true for specialised pure monads (e.g. [attoparsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.0.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Internal-Types.html#t:Parser)).

[As I already said](http://chrisdone.com/posts/pure-io-tryhaskell)), much simpler implementations are possible, they just wouldn't be as useful as the full-fledged optimised real-world `IO` type.

Fortunately, implementation needn't really bother you; the *inside* of `IO` may be unclear but the *outside*, the actual monadic interface, is pretty simple.

> in pure code evaluation order doesn't matter

First of all – evaluation order *can* matter in pure code!

```
Prelude> take 10 $ foldr (\h t -> h `seq` (h:t)) [] [0..]
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
Prelude> take 10 $ foldr (\h t -> t `seq` (h:t)) [] [0..]
^CInterrupted.
```

But indeed you can never get a wrong, *non-⊥* result due to misordered pure-code evaluation. That actually doesn't apply to reordering monadic actions (`IO` or otherwise) though, because changing the sequence order changes the actual *structure* of the resultant action, not just the evaluation order that the runtime will use to *construct* this structure.

For example (list monad):

```
Prelude> [1,2,3] >>= \e -> [10,20,30] >>= \z -> [e+z]
[11,21,31,12,22,32,13,23,33]
Prelude> [10,20,30] >>= \z -> [1,2,3] >>= \e -> [e+z]
[11,12,13,21,22,23,31,32,33]
```

---

All that said, certainly `IO` is quite special, indeed I think some people hesitate to call it a monad (it's a bit unclear what it's actually supposed to mean for `IO` to fulfill the monad laws). In particular, *lazy IO* is one massive troublemaker (and best just avoided, at all times).

Comment: when I say escape or run, I mean run* functions that allow us to execute state or reader actions. I think there is no safe run IO function. It would be nice to understand why

Comment: These `run*` functions do _not_ “execute” anything. They indeed just unwrap the internal representation. In the case of `IO`, this is not officially exported (but, as I said twice, there are alternative implementations of `IO` which boil down to a simple state monad).

Comment: @damluar Referential transparency. With a pure function, the compiler is free to replace, for example, `(\x -> x * x) y` with `y * y`. If `y` is an impure function, though, such a transformation changes the semantics, as `y`'s side effect takes place twice instead of once. Placing a function in the `IO` monad (by having it return an `IO` action) prevents you from being allowed to write unsafe code like this. You would have to write `y >>= (\x -> return (x * x))`, and the definition of `>>=` for the particular monad prevents unsafe expansion.

Comment: @damluar The `IO` monad is special in that `>>=` is not implemented in Haskell code, but in the interpreter/compiler itself, because that is the only piece allowed to deal directly with the external world. (Haskell code like `getChar` remains pure by only returning a *promise* to read a character, rather than actually returning a character that could be used to "infect" otherwise pure code.)

Comment: @chepner This isn't actually true, `>>=` for IO is a [regular function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html) (see `bindIO`). The runtime does know that `State# RealWorld` is a dummy parameter and to never e.g. allocated memory for it, and to not reorder cases on such parameters during compilation, for example. `IO` itself is really not primitive - `State#` is primtive.

Comment: @user2407038 Nice. I had actually been looking for that (to show that `IO` is basically a state monad), but assumed it wasn't there when I couldn't find an explicit `data IO a = ...` definition.

Comment: I'm confused by your `take 10 $ foldr (\h t -> h \`seq\` (h:t)) [] [0..]` example. It always returns `[0..9]` on my machine.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yeah, sure. As I wrote, that terminates just fine. The expression that doesn't terminate is ``take 10 $ foldr (\h t -> t `seq` (h:t)) [] [0..]``.

Comment: Whoops missed that the `h` became a `t`

Answer (score 2):

Similar statements could be made about the `ST` monad, or arguably the `STM` monad (although you can actually implement that one on top of `IO`).

Basically things like the Reader monad, Error monad, Writer monad, etc., are all just pure code. The `ST` and `IO` monads are the only ones that really do impure things (state mutation, etc), so they aren't definable in pure Haskell. They have to be "hard-wired" into the compiler somewhere.